# Need a little help to fix an Arduino RFID program

Tags: c, arduino, rfid, arduino-nano

I just extracted the problematic part of my program, I use **RFID.h** and **SPI.h**,
I just want to know how to read on a RFID card (written with an android phone)
I only write one letter : R, G, B, Y, ... (represent color)  , on an Android tool I can See at sector 04 : ?TenR? When the "R" after Ten is the string that I wanna read :

```
    char buffer_data[8];
    rfid.read(0x04,buffer_data);
  
    String myString = String(buffer_data);
    Serial.println(myString);
```

I only want to know how to output => "R" (text on the RFID card at sector 04) : It output something like that :

```
22:05:15.885 -> 
22:05:15.885 -> &⸮
22:05:15.885 -> ⸮⸮
```

With other cards (Y, B char inside) same output...

Screenshot with card data (Mifare classic 1k (716B writable)):

[image: screenshopt of card data + string that I want to read]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lib RFID.h with rfid.read doest not work...
https://github.com/song940/RFID-RC522
don't use this lib !

The lib https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid is better, up to date, and can read most of tag types !

This is the fixed code to read the first text char on NTAG215 :

```
if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
 if ( ! rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
   return;
 }
  Serial.println("");
  String str;
  byte buffer_data[18];
  byte size_data = sizeof(buffer_data);
  rfid.MIFARE_Read(4,buffer_data,&size_data);
  str=String((char *)buffer_data);
  Serial.println(str.charAt(9));
}
```

Ouput the first letter on the tag (if you write text data with Android NFC tools app ) only on NTAG215 (other tag = different adresses/position)!

Comment: Maybe their is a lib to read text for all sorts of tags ? but I didn't find it !

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the "square" refers to the ASCII number printed to stdout.
I would want to find out, what `read_char` is in HEX, so instead of printing it as a character to `stdout`, print the hex representation of it and see what value you get. It's difficult to give you more accurate troubleshooting steps with the limited system information available.

Comment: I just want how to use the read function, no doc :s I dont know how to read text from rfid.

Comment: Does not `char read_char=rfid.read(01,buffer1);` do the reading from your rfid? Where `buffer1` contains your rfid data?

Comment: yes it read something, when I go in the lib code, data are written  to buffer, but I doint know how to read it